# Delphi DLL Inject and sharing vars

Tags: dll, delphi-7, code-injection, delphi

I use BTMemoryModule to inject a DLL into a process. 
The Main/Parent Process can call a function/procedure but what about the other way?
Can a dll read/get a var from the Main/Parent process or call a function?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: 
DLL

```
library mydll; // DLL obviously...
uses windows;

procedure Test
begin
 // I need a string/integer/pointer from ParentProcess
end

exports
Test;

begin
 // I need a string/integer/pointer from ParentProcess. (if possible). 
end.
```

Program:

```
program myprogram
uses
...
var
 M : PBTMemoryModule;
begin
 BTMemoryLoadLibary (pointer, pointerlength);
 @myMaintest    := BTMemoryGetProcAddress(M, 'Test');
 ...
end;
```

Comment: This may be helpfull: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h90dkhs0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx "How do I share data in my DLL with an application or with other DLLs?")

Comment: thanks. but how can I use it in delphi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to expand my comment further to David's answer:

---

### DLL side:

1. Add in the DLL the **Init** procedure
2. Export it.
3. Add needed type/var declarations as needed

Snippet code:

```
library TheDLL;

...

var
  OwnerAPP: HMODULE; // To be initialized by a call of the exported procedure Init from the EXE

...

type
  TTestCallfromExe = procedure(f_Text: PAnsiChar); stdcall;

var
  OwnerAPP: LongInt;
  l_TestCallfromExe: TTestCallfromExe;

procedure Init(Owner: HMODULE);
begin
  OwnerAPP := Owner;
end;

...

exports
  Init, // This is it and the others exports follow
  ...
```

Call to **TestCallfromExe** is carried out like usual call to any Dll's exported function/procedure. A call can be made in the body of a Dll's exported function according the OP's requirements so long as **OwnerAPP** was correctly initialized.

---

### EXE side:

Export every procedure/function (to be called from DLL) as needed, of course you should implement each of them.

```
program TheEXE;

uses
  ...
  MyExportImplementation; // Refence to implementatio unit

...

exports
  TestCallfromExe, // This is it
  ...

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Sample implementation details:

```
unit MyExportImplementation;

interface

...

procedure TestCallfromExe(f_Text: PAnsiChar); stdcall;

implementation

...

procedure TestCallfromExe(f_Text: PAnsiChar); stdcall;
begin
  MessageBoxA(0, f_Text, 'Exe Dialog Ansi (stdcall)', 0);
end;

...

end.
```

---

### Putting it all together:

This is based on the DemoDLL (from BTMemory) sample, to implement for instance in the MainForm unit of the **TheEXE.dpr** project:

```
procedure TForm1.BtnCAllClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  l_Init: procedure(Owner: HMODULE);
begin
  m_DllHandle := LoadLibrary('TheDLL.dll');
  try
    if m_DllHandle = 0 then
      Abort;

    @l_Init := GetProcAddress(m_DllHandle, 'Init');  // <<<
    if @l_Init = nil then
      Abort;

    // Fetch the remainding exported function(s)/procedure(s) adresses

    l_Init(HInstance); // <<<  Hand EXE's HInstance over to the DLL

    // Call exported function(s)/procedure(s) accordingly
  except
    Showmessage('An error occured while loading the dll');
  end;

  if m_DllHandle <> 0 then
    FreeLibrary(m_DllHandle)
end;
```

---

### Nota Bene:

I tested it also with BTMemory and it works.

Comment: Use `HMODULE` as the type for the module handle. Otherwise your code will fail on x64 due to pointer truncation.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Edit made. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @David Heffernan: My answer is just an expansion of yours. Thanks to peer review it can be improved and as you lately suggests there are still room for improvement. Honestly, your answer contains more valuable information than mine. By the way, I noticed a weird (?) behavior of the code during testing it: It works without the prior call to **l_Init(HInstance)**. How comes it? My guess is that GetProcAddress does a smart inference retrieving the module instance by means of the adress of OwnerApp within the DLL (loaded in the EXE's adress space). Am I right?

Comment: I can't see your code that calls GetProcAddress from inside the EXE. You example is incomplete. I don't believe that calling GetProcAddress and passing `0` as the module handle will result in anything other than an error.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, that does not appear to be what is normally termed injection. That's just a plain module load, albeit from memory rather than file.

As for how the DLL can import functions from the EXE, do it in exactly the same way as when the EXE imports from the DLL.

1. Use `exports` to list the functions that the EXE exports.
2. Obtain the module handle of the EXE by calling `GetModuleHandle(nil)`.
3. Pass that module handle to `GetProcAddress` to import functions.

The only difference from the more common EXE linking to DLL pattern is that you use `GetModuleHandle` rather than `LoadLibrary`. And that's because the EXE must already be loaded so you can simply ask for its module handle rather than asking for the module to be loaded.

I would comment that it's pretty unusual to do things this way. Normally the EXE would call the DLL and pass whatever information was needed by the DLL. That information could include callback functions, interfaces etc. that would allow the DLL to query its host EXE.

Comment: +1: for using GetModuleHandle(nil). Instead, I thought of using a sort of initialization procedure exported by the DLL to fetch the HInstance of the EXE and called by the EXE (handing over the HInstance) prior to any reference to the other exports knowing that it's needed for any call to the EXE's exports.

Comment: @menjaraz That would work quite nicely too and is an example of the general technique I outline in the final paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

If the Child module (your DLL) knows the data structures and the functions of the Parent application, this is possible. These data and functions must be made available on the Parent side.

Comment: so how should I implement this? the DLL doesn't know any pointers (cause they are dynamic) when I compile it :/

Comment: can you share part of your code? Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240/How-to-share-a-data-segment-in-a-DLL. There are, of course, many ways to accomplish this feature.

Comment: Added code. The link is a sample for C and I don't think it's dynamic?! The shared segments are build when you compile them not in runtime?! Thank you tho :)

Comment: As mentioned, when you want to inject an image in another one, you must know what you are expecting, looking for and prepare the scenario. You can also share data dynamically using CreateFileMapping (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Like any rich API uses those Callbacks or Hooks - your EXE calls DLL and passes it data frame with all needed pointers - to variables, to functions, etc. Then DLL can use call them. Just like u create new window you pass windows the function to call, when users click it or such. HEre your application passes pointer to Windows GDI32.DLL and same way u might pass it to your own DLL.